# Apex batch not executing all records

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, force.com

I'm relatively new to Apex, but I have a question about a batch job that I am creating. I am trying to insert AccountTeamMember records based on my company's territory alignment. The code seems to be working fine, but with one flaw: it is only inserting 100 AccountTeamMember records per user (it should be closer to 400, as that is how many I have loaded in my dev sandbox). Does anyone know what I can do to get an AccountTeamMember record inserted for all accounts per user, rather than 100 of the ~400? Is it something to do with the query including parent-child relationships and governor limits since it is such an even number (100)?

Here is the relevant code:

```
//list to hold new account teams
List<AccountTeamMember> acctMembers = new List<AccountTeamMember>();

//list to hold new account sharing rules
List<AccountShare> acctSharingRules = new List<AccountShare>();

global Database.querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
String query = 'SELECT (SELECT User__c FROM Territory_Users__r), (SELECT Account__c FROM Territory_Accounts__r) FROM Territory_Master__c';
return Database.getQueryLocator(query);}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope){

for (sObject s : scope) {
    Territory_Master__c tm = (Territory_Master__c) s;
    Territory_User__c[] userList = tm.getSObjects('Territory_Users__r');
    Territory_Account__c[] accountList = tm.getSObjects('Territory_Accounts__r');


    if (userList != null && accountList != null){
        for(Territory_User__c uu : userList){
            for(Territory_Account__c aa: accountList){
                AccountTeamMember addRecord = new AccountTeamMember();
                addRecord.AccountId = aa.Account__c;
                addRecord.TeamMemberRole = 'Sales Rep';
                addRecord.UserId = uu.User__c;
                acctMembers.add(addRecord);

                AccountShare addSharing = new AccountShare();
                addSharing.AccountId = aa.Account__c;
                addSharing.OpportunityAccessLevel = 'Read';
                addSharing.CaseAccessLevel = 'Read';
                addSharing.AccountAccessLevel = 'Edit';
                addSharing.UserOrGroupId = uu.User__c;
                acctSharingRules.add(addSharing);

            }
        }
    }
}

//DML
if(acctMembers.size() > 0){
    insert acctMembers;
}
if(acctSharingRules.size() > 0){
    insert acctSharingRules;
}
}
```

Thanks,

Trey

FYI: This is the final result based on the answer to the question:

```
global Database.querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
String query = 'SELECT Id FROM Territory_Master__c';
return Database.getQueryLocator(query);}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope){

for(sObject s : scope){
    Territory_Master__c tm = (Territory_Master__c) s;

    List<Territory_User__c> userList = [SELECT User__c FROM Territory_User__c WHERE Territory_Master__c = :tm.Id];
    List<Territory_Account__c> accountList = [SELECT Account__c FROM Territory_Account__c WHERE Territory_Master__c = :tm.Id];

    if (userList != null && accountList != null){
        for(Territory_User__c uu : userList){
                for(Territory_Account__c aa: accountList){
                AccountTeamMember addRecord = new AccountTeamMember();
                addRecord.AccountId = aa.Account__c;
                addRecord.TeamMemberRole = 'Sales Rep';
                addRecord.UserId = uu.User__c;
                acctMembers.add(addRecord);

                acctSharingRules.add(new AccountShare(
                    AccountId = aa.Account__c,
                    OpportunityAccessLevel = 'Read',
                    CaseAccessLevel = 'Read',
                    AccountAccessLevel = 'Edit',
                    UserOrGroupId = uu.User__c)
                );
            }
        }
    }
}

//DML
if(acctMembers.size() > 0){
    insert acctMembers;
}
if(acctSharingRules.size() > 0){
    insert acctSharingRules;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your subqueries got limited and it's your job to make sure you've finished with this record before moving on to the next one.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm

> Subquery results are like regular query results in that you might need
>   to use queryMore() to retrieve all the records if there are many
>   children. For example, if you issue a query on accounts that includes
>   a subquery, your client application must handle results from the
>   subquery as well

(the example is for Java calling Salesforce so don't copy-paste the code, try to understand the concept. As far as I know Apex doesn't have this queryMore method, it's for integrations only)

**Option 1**

Funny enough, it should in theory work if you'd change the for loops to this:

```java
for(Territory_User__c uu : tm.getSObjects('Territory_Users__r')){
    for(Territory_Account__c aa: tm.getSObjects('Territory_Accounts__r'))
```

That's because for loops written in that way [should automatically call their internal queryMore()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_loops_for_SOQL.htm).

If it won't work (I haven't tested it), you'll have to make a bit more complex changes.

**Option 2**

Remove the subqueries from the main query, you'll have to put them in the execute(). Something like this:

```java
for(sObject s : scope){
    Territory_Master__c tm = (Territory_Master__c) s;

    for(Territory_User__c uu : [SELECT User__c FROM Territory_User__c WHERE Territory_Master__c = :tm.Id]){
        for(Territory_Account__c aa: [SELECT Account__c FROM Territory_Account__c WHERE Territory_Master__c = :tm.Id]){
            acctMembers.add(new AccountTeamMember(
                AccountId = aa.Account__c,
                TeamMemberRole = 'Sales Rep',
                UserId = uu.User__c)
            );

            acctSharingRules.add(new AccountShare(
                AccountId = aa.Account__c,
                OpportunityAccessLevel = 'Read',
                CaseAccessLevel = 'Read',
                AccountAccessLevel = 'Edit',
                UserOrGroupId = uu.User__c)
            );
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Side notes**

1. Is there a chance you'll hit a limit of 50K rows retrieved across all objects (Territory Master/User/Account? If that's the case you might have to limit the scope of your batch job (optional second parameter passed to the [`Database.executeBatch()`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_database.htm)).
2. This trick can make your script execute bit faster and use less statements (so you won't hit another governor limit):

   ```java
   acctSharingRules.add(new AccountShare(
       AccountId = aa.Account__c,
       OpportunityAccessLevel = 'Read',
       CaseAccessLevel = 'Read',
       AccountAccessLevel = 'Edit',
       UserOrGroupId = uu.User__c)
   );
   ```

Comment: Very helpful answer. Option 1 unfortunately behaved as my original code did, but you nailed it with Option 2. I slightly modified your code to fit the logic and the final result works flawlessly. I also took into account your side notes. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad to help plus I've learned something myself too :) Actually I've had a brainfart moment. Ignore the bit about 50K rows read. Your biggest worry should be 10K rows inserted in each context (so each `execute()` call) ;)

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing obviously wrong with your code there, so if I were you I'd try to narrow down the cause of the problem.  The source of the problem is going to be one of:

- Your query is only returning 100 items in accountList or userList or both
- The insert can only handle 100 items at a time and is silently failing to insert the rest
- The insert is failing for the items after 100

If you haven't already done so, you should familiarize yourself with using Debug Logs in Salesforce.com (Setup | Monitoring | Debug Logs).  Turn them on, then run this code with some System.debug calls in there to figure out:

- How many items are in userList and accountList?
- If it's more than 100, when you go to insert the share rows, are some of those inserts failing?  If you use Database.insert() instead of just the insert statement then you'll get a SaveResult[] back that will tell you for each row you attempted to insert whether it was successful or errored out.

So I can't say off the top of my head why this is failing, and I don't see any particular limit that should apply here, but the above should help you debug it at least.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was able to get it working with a slight recode.